# limiting a join to avoid long query run-time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query that finds two-way connections in a table that keeps one-way connections through a join to itself:

```
    SELECT tbl1.to, LEAST( tbl2.counter, tbl1.counter ) AS minCounter
    FROM connections tbl1
       INNER JOIN connections tbl2 ON tbl2.from = tbl1.to
       WHERE tbl1.from =<user_id>
             AND tbl2.to =<user_id>
       ORDER BY LEAST( tbl2.counter, tbl1.counter ) DESC 
       LIMIT 15
```

This is performing reasonably well, but sometimes when there are a lot of `from` connections it becomes too slow. The tradeoff I'm looking to make is to make it less accurate and add a limit to the amount of `from` connections he actually uses for the join in the query. Is that possible?

Comment: How slow is slow? How many records do the tables contain? Do you have proper indexes?

Comment: @GolezTrol Table has ~1.5B rows and is 110GB. I have proper indexes. Too slow for me is more than a couple of seconds (>5).

Answer (score 1):

5 seconds for a join on 1.5B rows sounds not too bad. But one reason for this query being slow, is when it would return a lot of rows without the `limit` clause. That is because you specify a sort order as well. Ordering and adding a limit will cause the full results to be ordered first, in order do determine *which* 15 rows it should return.

If you are willing to sacrify accuracy for better performance, try to remove the `order by`, or order it after limiting the results.

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT tbl1.to, LEAST( tbl2.counter, tbl1.counter ) AS minCounter
    FROM connections tbl1
       INNER JOIN connections tbl2 ON tbl2.from = tbl1.to
       WHERE tbl1.from =<user_id>
             AND tbl2.to =<user_id>
       LIMIT 15)
ORDER BY minCounter DESC
```

Alternatively, you can try to limit the number of records first to a reasonable number (500 in this example), then do the sorting and limit again. This way, the results will be 100% accurate for users with up to 500 results and less accurate for those with more.

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT tbl1.to, LEAST( tbl2.counter, tbl1.counter ) AS minCounter
    FROM connections tbl1
       INNER JOIN connections tbl2 ON tbl2.from = tbl1.to
       WHERE tbl1.from =<user_id>
             AND tbl2.to =<user_id>
       LIMIT 500)
ORDER BY minCounter DESC 
LIMIT 15
```

Comment: Whenever the amount of `from` matches is reasonable, the running time is ok, so I'm looking to only sacrifice accuracy in cases where there are many `from` matches, and that's why I thought about limiting the `from` matches the query is looking at. Diving to queries can do this simply, but trying to avoid that. I guess that's not possible in the query? Also, can you add example to how I can order after the limit in the query?

Comment: You could put it in a subselect, like I've added to my answer. It might improve results, but in some cases it can be slower, since MySQL doesn't handle subqueries very well all the time. Try and see.

Comment: Apparently I cancelled my edit. Re-added the query and a possible solution to keep accuracy for users with less results.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have in the `WHERE` clause both conditions because you already joined your tables on the user. Also do not forget about having proper indexes in `to`, `from` and `counter` (because of the order).

Also be careful with the `ORDER BY LEAST()`. Try without it and and I am sure it will be a big difference.

```
SELECT tbl1.to, LEAST( tbl2.counter, tbl1.counter ) AS minCounter
FROM connections tbl1
   INNER JOIN connections tbl2 ON tbl2.from = tbl1.to
   WHERE tbl1.from =<user_id>
   ORDER BY tbl2.counter DESC, tbl1.counter DESC 
   LIMIT 15
```